# В связке NGINX и Tomcat. Tomcat не получает ip клиента

Tags: nginx, tomcat, proxy

в связке Nginx + tomcat не получается передать реальный IP клиента.
По логам Nginx вижу IP клиента, выполняется редирект 301, выполняется прокси proxy_pass на локальный хост, на котором слушает tomcat, но в логах tomcat уже адрес не клиента а локального хоста 127.0.0.1

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name _;
        expires -1;
        return       301 http://my.syte.ua/promo-site/get?url=$scheme://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.syte.ua;
    
location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

Comment: По словам "tomcat x-real-ip" гугль первой строчкой советует это: https://serverfault.com/questions/514551/make-tomcat-use-x-real-ip

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает, я на это решение не натыкался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Alexander Prokoshev за ответ! Дублирую его здесь.

Требуется добавить Valve в конфигурацию Tomcat:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
               remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For"
               requestAttributesEnabled="true"
               internalProxies="127\.0\.0\.1"  />
```

После этого Tomcat начинает отправлять заголовки, переданные из nginx:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```